# ASP.Net authentication, redirecting different page for specific pages

Tags: asp.net, authentication

For example i'm redirecting users to login.aspx for authentication but i want to redirect some pages to another-login.aspx is it possible?
If it is possible how can i do?
I can do it by using some codes on that pages load event but i want to know if its possible with normal authentication rules.

Comment: Your question isn't clear! What is exactly you want?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I don't see how this could be possible.  The authentication just checks if a user is able to view a page, unless of course you had a redirect from the authentication when it failed to a different page (another-login.aspx).  That is the only way that I think you could do this, but you would still be hitting the initial page (login.aspx) to check if the end user had the authority to view that page.  So, I don't see the benefit in doing it this way as it would still be hitting your initial page.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way I think you can achieve this is to have redirect code on your Page_Load for your main login.

Something like:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 { 
     if (codition1) 
      { 
            Response.Redirect(@"\Login1.aspx"); 
      } 
     else if(condition2) 
     { 
      Response.Redirect(@"\Login2.aspx"); 
      } 
 }
```